# How can write a vector from the resistor to the node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I haven´t be able to make a vector from `$R_1$` to the node `$B$` without changing the resistor orientation. Does anyone know how to do it?

```
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw 
  (0,0) -- (0,2)
  node[label={[font=\footnotesize]left:$\mathrm{A}$}]{}
  (8,2) -- (8,0)
  node[label={[font=\footnotesize]right:$\mathrm{D}$}]{}
  (0,2)
  to node[draw,circle,fill=white] {A} (4,2)
  (4,2)
  to[resistor, l=$R_1$] (8,2)
  node[label={[font=\footnotesize]right:$\mathrm{B}$}]{}
  (4,0)
  to[battery1, l =$V_1$, i<^=$I_p$, -*] (8,0)
  (0,0)
  node[label={[font=\footnotesize]left:$\mathrm{C}$}]{}
  to[resistor, l= $R_2$, i<^=$I_2$, *-] (4,0)
  (0,-2)
  node[label={[font=\footnotesize]left:$\mathrm{E}$}]{}
  to[resistor, l= $R_3$, i<^=$I_3$, *-] (4,-2)
  (4,-2)
  to[battery1, l =$V_2$, i<^=$I_q$, -*] (8,-2)
  (8,0)
  to[short, i=${}$] (8,-2)
  (8,-2)
  node[label={[font=\footnotesize]right:$\mathrm{F}$}]{}
  (4,0)
  to node[draw,circle,fill=white] {V} (4,-2)
  (0,-2) -- (0,-4)
  node[label={[font=\footnotesize]left:$\mathrm{G}$}]{}
  (8,-4)
  to[resistor, l= $R_4$, i<^=$I_4$] (0,-4)
  (8,-2) -- (8,-4)
  node[label={[font=\footnotesize]right:$\mathrm{H}$}]{}
  (0,-2)
  to[short, i=${}$] (0,0)
;
\end{circuitikz}
```

Comment: With vector, do you mean a current arrow? If so, just putting `i=$I_1$` after `l=$R_1$` should work.

Comment: Or `f=$I_1$` if you prefer flow-style arrows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to show one solution *and* what a correct *minimal* example should be... and also showing an easier way to build the circuit.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
  (0,2)
  node[left, font=\footnotesize]{A}
  to[rmeterwa, t=A] (4,2)
  to[resistor, l=$R_1$, i=$I_1$] (8,2)
  node[right, font=\footnotesize]{B}
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another solution is with "flows" and with relative coordinates; notice that this way you can move the branch wherever you want just changing the *first* coordinate...

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
  (0,2)
  node[left, font=\footnotesize]{A}
  to[rmeterwa, t=A] ++(4,0)
  to[resistor, l=$R_1$, f=$I_1$] ++(4,0)
  node[right, font=\footnotesize]{B}
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]